# What does return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) do?

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

1. It's given in the android docs of onOptionItemSelected that `When you successfully handle a menu item, return true. If you don't handle the menu item, you should call the superclass implementation of onOptionsItemSelected() (the default implementation returns false).`.But I don't get what the last one means. what does it mean by saying `call the superclass implementation of onOptionItemSelected`. What does calling the superclass do
2. Also please do explain what `return.super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` do?

Comment: what do you think it does? it causes a compilation error, because there shouldn't be a . between return and super. without that point, it returns the result of the onOptionsItemSelected(item) method of it's parent class

Comment: Nop still can't understand what the last line means